# register for face_recognition

Tags: python, registration, face-recognition, image-registration

I'm trying to do an basic register for my face_recognition app using python

```
#Here I'm trying to register faces more easier than need to add every face editing my script
```

I need some way to add persons, register that and then can be recognized
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Thats all my code test, I'm trying to do whats my friend here say to I do but I new in python so I will need a more help.

This is a face_recognition code, I'm studing python for aprimorate this code for help me in the university! so I great for all yours helps

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
from PIL import Image


video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

image_of_patricia = face_recognition.load_image_file("./img/known/Patricia.jpg")
patricia_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_of_patricia)[0]

image_of_victor = face_recognition.load_image_file("./img/known/Victor.jpg")
victor_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_of_victor)[0]

image_of_henrique = face_recognition.load_image_file("./img/known/Henrique_.PNG")
henrique_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_of_henrique)[0]

# create array of encoddings and names

known_face_encodings = [
     patricia_face_encoding,
     victor_face_encoding,
     ricardo_face_encoding,
]

known_face_names = [
     "Patricia",
     "Victor",
     "Henrique",
     "Ricardo"
]

face_encodings = []
face_locations = []
faces_names = []
face_landmarks_list = []
process_this_frame = True


while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    if process_this_frame:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame,)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(Known_face_encodings, face_encoding, tolerance=0.65)


            name = "Unknown"

            if True in  matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = known_face_names[first_match_index]


            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame



    for(top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):

        top *= 4 
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        #font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        #cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        if name == "Victor":
            print("Victor")

        elif name == "Patricia":
            print("Patricia")

        elif name == "Ricardo":
            print("Ricardo")

        elif name == "Henrique":
            print("Henrique")
        elif name == "Desconhecido":
            #cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            #cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
            #cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            print("desconhecido")


    cv2.imshow("Reconhecimento Facial", frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord("q"):
        break


video_capture.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, you could do something like this:

```
class KnowledgeBase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []
        self.faces = []


    def register_face(self, name, img_path):
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img_path) 
        encoded_face = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
        self.names.append(name)
        self.faces.append(encoded_face)
```

Then you just need to instantiate a KnowledgeBase element and add new data to it. This can be in a separate file if you want:

```
kb = KnowledgeBase()
kb.register_face('Patricia', './img/known/Patricia.jpg')
kb.register_face('Victor', './img/known/Victor.jpg')
kb.register_face('Henrique', './img/known/Henrique_.PNG')
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help! I'm trying to apply that in the my code but it's don't working... I will send the hole code for descovered whats going wrong! thank one more time